Triggering 1 machine to turn on with another machine
Ok I'm going to try and explain this the best I can.
We have a machine at work that is water cooled and we are adding a fan to help cool it down.
However I want to have it on a timer so when it starts it will stay on for at lest 30 mins after the machine shuts off. Now I have that under control no problems however I want to be able to trigger the fan to turn on when the water solenoid opens so its not running all the time.
So to break it down I need to power a 110v fan with a delay timer but I want the trigger to be a different 110v circuit ( the solenoid power source ) So far I am using a Simens sirius ( 3rp1505-1aq30 ) and I have that hooked to a push button as the trigger. but I am lost how to get the fan to kick on when the cooling water solenoid opens.
Thanks!

Just for discussion purposes, let's say this is a laser cutter system that uses a separate water cooler box during operation. And that when it is shut off (laser and water cooler), then the fan should be turned on for 30 minutes. Would that be about right? Or am I completely misreading?

very close! the system is a pump for a waterjet and yes we use a water cooler that runs cold water into the pumps hydraulic heat exchanger. they are 2 different systems yes.  The water in solenoid is controlled by a thermostat that gives it 110v when it is time to add water to cool the pump down. Now at first I did think just to run the fan off that circuit and add the timer to it BUT after digging that circuit  is only around 2 amps not enough to run the fan. I want to run the fan on its own power p but I want the timer to trigger from the thermostat opening the cold water solenoid.

So the water cooling system is ON/OFF control, which means it alternates between ON and OFF depending on temp. This doesn't sound like a good thing to observe for the fan, since the fan will be turned on when the water pump is turned off and it will stay on for 30 minutes because of what you wrote you wanted, even if the system is still in operation and the water pump is turned back on in 5 minutes because the system is still running and being used. Did you want that? Doesn't sound right to me. I'm not applying my brain much here -- mostly letting you be the guide.

Its really hard to explain. When the pump is running and the temp of the hydraulic oil reaches 120 degrees the thermostat open the solenoid letting in the cold water from the chiller unit. So what I want is when the solenoid opens to let the chilled water in I want the fan to kick on with it and run for around 30 mins after the solenoid closes or the pump is turned off.  Where the pump is its a corner with very little air flow so I want to fan to help cool it down even after the pump turns off.

Very good. Makes more sense to me now. I know you may think that the comments here are good enough. But it may still be a good idea now to update your question, incorporating what you wrote into the question itself. This will go a long way in getting better answers. Some folks may miss details in the comments or otherwise attempt to answer their own interpretation of the question as it stands right now. Many know enough to read comments, too. I'm not taking that away. But I'd suggest considering putting these important details into the question itself. Also, how many amps for the fan??

Oh. One more thing. There is something called a monostable multivibrator and it can be retriggerable, or not. One that is retriggerable would reset the 30 seconds each time the solenoid opens even if only 5 seconds goes by. One that isn't retriggerable would wait out the 30 seconds regardless of the number of times the solenoid opens during that period. Regardless, this is what you are looking for -- monostable multivibrator -- one that can drive your fan and be triggered by the opening of the solenoid.

The fan is pretty small only around 2 amps. As of now I have it setup with a siemens timing relay and a push button. That works but It would be nice to not have to hit the button every time ya know ? I am just not sure where to go with this from here. has to be a simple way to have the 110v circuit from the pump trigger the other 110 circuit on the timing relay to start the fan up when needed.

The monostable timing is usually based on DC, not AC. Nothing is coming immediately to mind that doesn't include some DC bit to it. So even though it may seem counter-intuitive, I think a small DC supply may be required. Could be a battery. The AC applied to the solenoid can be used to trip a tiny relay that initiates the DC circuit. The DC circuit would control another relay for the fan. For the fan, this could either be an AC-powered relay or a DC-powered relay. There may be some commercial off the shelf unit that does all this. Might check ebay or something. I don't know the search words.

I'll have to dig around some more has to be something out to pull this off. Thanks for your help!

Might look at the "F" version of this. I didn't spend a lot of time there, but if you go down on the sheet you will see a timing diagram. Looks like it might help. Probably several people here know a lot more about these things than I do. So perhaps they will chip in, later.

To improve your question description, I suggest you avoid ambiguous phases with pronouns/articles that simply confuse the reader.  Some examples from your Q: "explain this the best I can"= explain what?  "this" is empty.  "I want to have it on a timer", unclear here if "it" is the "machine" (the last use of "it" in prior sentence") or the "fan".  "Now I have that under control", what is the "that" here ("turning off the machine" or "turning off the fan")?  Also, don't assume the reader knows about random equipment, such as "using a Simens sirius ( 3rp1505-1aq30 )", please explain this device.

What happens when the "push button" currently used as the trigger is pressed?  I'm assuming this push button is momentary switch and that the trigger causes the fan to initially turn on and then the existing timer starts, correct?  But what happens if the button is pressed again 15 minutes later?  does the timer reset to 30 more minutes or something else?  what happens when the button is held continuously active/pushed?

When you push the button it starts the timer. If you hold the button it will stay on continuously once you release the button the timer starts. If you press it while the timer is running it will reset the timer.

@ShaneRatajczakSR That's called a "re-triggerable" timer. Your need for holding the button beyond the timing period does mean this isn't strictly a re-triggerable monostable, though. But it's an easy modification to achieve that result. My problem in even attempting an answer is that I don't know your solenoid (the one that opens) circuit details. One might assume. But I won't assume anything about it. I need to know exactly what that circuit looks like to know what I may and may not use as a signal to drive the rest of the circuit. Others are smarter about this than I and can assume better.

@ShaneRatajczakSR Write more about the situation and perhaps I (or others) can make a helpful suggestion.

Here's how, using two contactors and an on-delay timer.

